# Padding in FlowListView Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My problem i not found padding in FlowListView Plugin i want to make Like this picture but the green Layout not show the last item in list, how can i do that if not use padding?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G29lf.png).

Comment: If you want to have some space between FlowListView and Green Layout, you can try to set Margin for FlowListView.

Comment: No the green box overlap on ListView , so i want to add padding at the bottom of List

Comment: Yes, you said that the Green Box overlap on FlowListView, so you want to change this situation. I don't know how do you place flowListView and Green Box, but the Padding property represents the distance between an element and its child elements, and is used to separate the control from its own content.The Thickness Padding values for the layout.